# How do I configure an Apache 2.4 virtual server to run a perl script

Tags: php, apache-2.4, ubuntu-18.04, cgi-bin

Using webmin I setup an Apache virtual server under ubuntu 18.04. Server directives are:

```
DocumentRoot /home/name/public_html
ServerName www.name.com
<Directory "/home/name/public_html">
    allow from all
    Options None
    Require all granted
    Options ExecCGI
</Directory>
```

I have perl scripts in two directories, /cgi-bin/A/a.cgi and /cgi-bin/B/b.cgi. I have two PHP scripts delivering two web pages, a.php and b.php with links that connect to these scripts. When I click on <a href="/cgi-bin/A/a.cgi" the link works correctly and the perl script returns its output. However, when I click on <a href="/cgi-bin/B/b.cgi" I get "script not found or unable to stat: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/B".

I am perplexed as to how the first link works but the second doesn't, even though they are otherwise identical. Why is Apache replacing the /cgi-bin/B file path with /usr/lib/cgi-bin/B but not /cgi-bin/A?
Thanks in advance for help.